# Oracle query slow when joining, fast when splitted into two queries

Tags: sql, performance, oracle, query-optimization, sql-execution-plan

I have a sql query which is quite slow when joining two tables but is fast when I first query one table and with its output query the other table.

**Environment/Preconditions**

Oracle Version:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production

Objects involved:
cfc_materialized (materialized view, 21,5 Mio rows)
contact (table, 12,6 Mio rows)

Indexes involved:
CREATE INDEX CONTACT_CLIENT ON CONTACT(CLIENT);
CREATE INDEX CFC_MATERIALIZED_A_S_T ON CFC_MATERIALIZED(ASSOCIATION_TYPE, SOURCEID, TARGETID);

I have already recalculated the statistics of the 2 tables with cascade => true:

```
BEGIN
  SYS.DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS (
     OwnName        => '...'
    ,TabName        => '...'
    ,Estimate_Percent  => 0
    ,Degree            => 4
    ,Cascade           => TRUE
    ,No_Invalidate     => FALSE);
END;
/
```

**Problem**

I have the following query:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM contact c
WHERE c.client in (
    SELECT cfc.targetid
    FROM cfc_materialized cfc
    WHERE cfc.sourceid = 'e95027f0-a83e-11e3-a0ae-005056aebabc'
      AND cfc.association_type = 'ContactDataSharing'
  )
  AND c.deleted = 0;
```

Explain plan:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                      | Name             | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |    TQ  |IN-OUT| PQ Distrib |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT               |                  |    11M|  2214M| 38976   (1)| 00:07:48 |        |      |            |
|   1 |  PX COORDINATOR                |                  |       |       |            |          |        |      |            |
|   2 |   PX SEND QC (RANDOM)          | :TQ10001         |       |       |            |          |  Q1,01 | P->S | QC (RAND)  |
|   3 |    NESTED LOOPS                |                  |       |       |            |          |  Q1,01 | PCWP |            |
|   4 |     NESTED LOOPS               |                  |    11M|  2214M| 38976   (1)| 00:07:48 |  Q1,01 | PCWP |            |
|   5 |      SORT UNIQUE               |                  |  2164 |   196K| 10672   (1)| 00:02:09 |  Q1,01 | PCWP |            |
|   6 |       PX RECEIVE               |                  |  2164 |   196K| 10672   (1)| 00:02:09 |  Q1,01 | PCWP |            |
|   7 |        PX SEND HASH            | :TQ10000         |  2164 |   196K| 10672   (1)| 00:02:09 |  Q1,00 | P->P | HASH       |
|   8 |         PX BLOCK ITERATOR      |                  |  2164 |   196K| 10672   (1)| 00:02:09 |  Q1,00 | PCWC |            |
|*  9 |          MAT_VIEW ACCESS FULL  | CFC_MATERIALIZED |  2164 |   196K| 10672   (1)| 00:02:09 |  Q1,00 | PCWP |            |
|* 10 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN          | CONTACT_CLIENT   |  5500 |       |    37   (0)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,01 | PCWP |            |
|* 11 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| CONTACT          |  5474 |   550K|   973   (0)| 00:00:12 |  Q1,01 | PCWP |            |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   9 - filter("CFC"."SOURCEID"='e95027f0-a83e-11e3-a0ae-005056aebabc' AND "CFC"."ASSOCIATION_TYPE"='ContactDataSharing')
  10 - access("C"."CLIENT"="CFC"."TARGETID")
  11 - filter("C"."DELETED"=0)enter code here
```

This takes quite long and I am wondering why there is a full access on cfc_materialized.
When I split the query into 2 queries, it is much more faster.
1st query:

```
SELECT cfc.targetid
FROM cfc_materialized cfc
WHERE cfc.sourceid = 'e95027f0-a83e-11e3-a0ae-005056aebabc'
  AND cfc.association_type = 'ContactDataSharing';
```

This query returns 2 targetids.
Explain plan:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation        | Name                   | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT |                        |  2164 |   196K|    36   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  INDEX RANGE SCAN| CFC_MATERIALIZED_A_S_T |  2164 |   196K|    36   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - access("CFC"."ASSOCIATION_TYPE"='ContactDataSharing' AND 
              "CFC"."SOURCEID"='e95027f0-a83e-11e3-a0ae-005056aebabc')
```

Here the 2nd query. I use the output of the 1st query as input for the IN-parameter:

```
SELECT *
FROM contact c
WHERE c.client in (
    'e95027f0-a83e-11e3-a0ae-005056aebabc',
    'eb37d3b0-a83e-11e3-a0ae-005056aebabc'
  )
  AND c.deleted = 0;
```

Explain plan:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                    | Name           | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT             |                |  2814 |   283K|   505   (0)| 00:00:07 |
|   1 |  INLIST ITERATOR             |                |       |       |            |          |
|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| CONTACT        |  2814 |   283K|   505   (0)| 00:00:07 |
|*  3 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN          | CONTACT_CLIENT |  2827 |       |    23   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - filter("C"."DELETED"=0)
   3 - access("C"."CLIENT"='e95027f0-a83e-11e3-a0ae-005056aebabc' OR 
              "C"."CLIENT"='eb37d3b0-a83e-11e3-a0ae-005056aebabc')
```

**Question**

So my question is, why is the CBO not executing the query in a similar way like doing it in 2 queries manually? I also tried the query with hints to use the same indexes like in the 2 queries:

```
SELECT /*+ index(c CONTACT_CLIENT) */ c.*
FROM contact c
WHERE c.client in (
    SELECT /*+ index(cfc CFC_MATERIALIZED_A_S_T) */ cfc.targetid
    FROM cfc_materialized cfc
    WHERE cfc.sourceid = 'e95027f0-a83e-11e3-a0ae-005056aebabc'
      AND cfc.association_type = 'ContactDataSharing'
  )
  AND c.deleted = 0;
```

But then I get an even worse explain plan:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                    | Name                   | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT             |                        |    11M|  2214M|   305K  (1)| 01:01:09 |
|   1 |  NESTED LOOPS                |                        |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   NESTED LOOPS               |                        |    11M|  2214M|   305K  (1)| 01:01:09 |
|   3 |    SORT UNIQUE               |                        |  2164 |   196K|    36   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN         | CFC_MATERIALIZED_A_S_T |  2164 |   196K|    36   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  5 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN          | CONTACT_CLIENT         |  5500 |       |    37   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  6 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| CONTACT                |  5474 |   550K|   973   (0)| 00:00:12 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   4 - access("CFC"."ASSOCIATION_TYPE"='ContactDataSharing' AND 
              "CFC"."SOURCEID"='e95027f0-a83e-11e3-a0ae-005056aebabc')
   5 - access("C"."CLIENT"="CFC"."TARGETID")
   6 - filter("C"."DELETED"=0)
```

I also tried to do a join instead of an IN clause like suggested by Alexander and StanislavL:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM contact c
JOIN cfc_materialized cfc ON c.client = cfc.targetid
WHERE cfc.sourceid = 'e95027f0-a83e-11e3-a0ae-005056aebabc'
  AND cfc.association_type = 'ContactDataSharing'
  AND c.deleted = 0;
```

and got the following explain plan, which is again quite slow (slower than the two separate queries):

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name                   | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |                        |    11M|  2214M| 51745   (1)| 00:10:21 |
|*  1 |  HASH JOIN         |                        |    11M|  2214M| 51745   (1)| 00:10:21 |
|*  2 |   INDEX RANGE SCAN | CFC_MATERIALIZED_A_S_T |  2164 |   196K|    36   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  3 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| CONTACT                |    12M|  1237M| 51649   (1)| 00:10:20 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - access("C"."CLIENT"="CFC"."TARGETID")
   2 - access("CFC"."ASSOCIATION_TYPE"='ContactDataSharing' AND 
              "CFC"."SOURCEID"='e95027f0-a83e-11e3-a0ae-005056aebabc')
   3 - filter("C"."DELETED"=0)
```

Comment: Also, I believe, index on `cfc_materialized.targetid` is needed here

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.*
FROM contact c
    join (
    SELECT cfc.targetid as client
    FROM cfc_materialized cfc
    WHERE cfc.sourceid = 'e95027f0-a83e-11e3-a0ae-005056aebabc'
      AND cfc.association_type = 'ContactDataSharing'
  ) sub ON c.client=sub.client
  AND c.deleted = 0;
```

Use join rather than `IN` to avoid calculation of the same query for each row in `WHERE`

Comment: Why do you think query will be calculated more than once?

Answer (score 0):

Mainly, avoid full table access on `Contact` table.
Avoid `c.*`, specify concrete list of columns.
Rebuild the index

`CREATE INDEX CFC_MATERIALIZED_A_S_T ON CFC_MATERIALIZED(TARGETID, ASSOCIATION_TYPE, SOURCEID);`

Control join order access.

Let me know.